# How to show that the set of all polynomial is of the first category?

Tags: functional-analysis

Just like the title.

How to show the set of all polynomials on $C[a,b]$ (denoted by $P$) is of the first category?

I try to represent $P$ by a union of $P_n$, with $P_n$ is the set of polynomials on $C[a,b]$ which has a highest exponent $n$. How to show that each $P_n$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: The complement is open and dense.

Comment: I have completed the proof. Thanks!

Comment: Cool :) if you want, you can post an answer here, then people can give you feedback

Comment: If you are using "sparse set" to mean "nowhere dense set", then I would advise not to, since there are several non-equivalent meanings of "sparse set" in the mathematical literature (one of which is a kind of very strong nowhere dense set, in fact), whereas "nowhere dense set" is a standard term and is not going to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

For each $P_n$, consider $P_n^c$ as its complement.

For $\forall f\in C[a,b]$, if $f\notin P_n$, then $f\in P_n^c$. Otherwise, $f\in P_n$, consider a sequence of polynomials in $P_{n+1}$, having coefficients of items with exponent no greater than $n$ the same with those in $f$, and coefficients of $x^{n+1}$ converge to $0$. Then $f$ is a limit point of $P_n^c$ since $P_{n+1}\in P_n^c$.

Hence $P_n^c$ is dense and $P_n$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: You need to be slightly more careful. First of all $P_{n+1} \subset P_n^c$ (not element of). Also you need to show that $P_n^c$ is open, otherwise there is no reason for $P_n$ to be nowhere dense (for example $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but this does not imply that the irrationals are nowhere dense). In fact it more convenient to show that $P_n$ is closed (you can for example use the fact that it is finite-dimensional)